# Mars Rover Python exercise

Tags: python, algorithm

I have given the Mars Rover challenge a go in Python.

(edit) Here is the challenge, for those unfamiliar:

*A rover’s position and location is represented by a combination of x and y co-ordinates and a letter representing one of the four cardinal compass points. The plateau is divided up into a grid to simplify navigation. An example position might be 0, 0, N, which means the rover is in the bottom left corner and facing North.*

*In order to control a rover , NASA sends a simple string of letters. The possible letters are ‘L’, ‘R’ and ‘M’. ‘L’ and ‘R’ makes the rover spin 90 degrees left or right respectively, without moving from its current spot. ‘M’ means move forward one grid point, and maintain the same heading.*

*Test Input:*

5 5

1 2 N

LMLMLMLMM

3 3 E

MMRMMRMRRM

*Expected Output:*

1 3 N

5 1 E

I am still relatively new to Python so know this is a bit basic - but I wondered if I could get some general feedback on my code for best coding practice?

```
class MarsRover():


    RIGHT_ROTATE = {
        'N':'E',
        'E':'S',
        'S':'W',
        'W':'N'
    }

    LEFT_ROTATE = {
        'N':'W',
        'W':'S',
        'S':'E',
        'E':'N'
    }


    def __init__(self, X, Y, direction):

        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y
        self.direction = direction


    def rotate_right(self):

        self.direction = RIGHT_ROTATE[self.direction]


    def rotate_left(self):

        self.direction = LEFT_ROTATE[self.direction]


    def move(self):

        if self.direction == 'N':
            self.Y += 1
        elif self.direction == 'E':
            self.X += 1
        elif self.direction == 'S':
            self.Y -= 1    
        elif self.direction == 'W':
            self.X -= 1

    def __str__(self):

        return str(self.X) + " " + str(self.Y) + " " + self.direction

    @classmethod
    def get_rover_position(self):

        position = input("Position:")
        X = int(position[0])
        Y = int(position[2])
        direction = position[4]




class Plateau():



    def __init__(self, height, width):

        self.height = height
        self.width = width

    @classmethod
    def get_plateau_height(self):

        plateau_size = input("Plateau size:")
        height = int(plateau_size[0])
        width = int(plateau_size[2])



def main():

    plateau = Plateau.get_plateau_height()

    rover = MarsRover.get_rover_position()        

    current_command = 0 
    command = input("Please input directions for rover.")
    command_length = len(command)

    while current_command <= command_length - 1:

        if command[current_command] == 'L':
            rover.rotate_left()
            current_command += 1
        elif command[current_command] == 'R':
            rover.rotate_right()
            current_command += 1
        elif command[current_command] == 'M':
            rover.move()
            current_command += 1 


    result = str(rover)
    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

I am also getting the following error when I run the code:

```
     94         if command[current_command] == 'L':
---> 95             rover.rotate_left()
     96             current_command += 1
     97         elif command[current_command] == 'R':

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rotate_left'
```

Is anyone able to shed some light on why the 'rover' object is of NoneType?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the Mars Rover challenge? A bit of exposition would be great for those unfamiliar. Also, if the code isn't working as you expect, it's [off-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for CR.

Comment: Do not edit the code once you have received an answer, as your code changes can invalidate that answer.  You can ask a follow up question to have the changed code looked at.

Comment: if you have fixed your errors please post a new question,  make sure to check out our [How to ask a good question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for pointers on how to get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

`get_rover_position` does not return anything, and therefore the variable is None. You need to instantiate `MarsRover` in that class method with the provided input and return the newly created instance. The same applies also to `get_plateau_height`.

Comment: Next time, please refrain from answering off-topic questions. Questions have to be within scope of the site before they can be answered and code that throws blatant errors like this is not fit. Thank you.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the heads up.